# How to automate Desktop Notification in selenium webdriver - ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

[image: Gmail Desktop Notification]

I am trying to be able to get the data from gmail desktop notification using selenium webdriver in ruby

Comment: seems related to [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526754/undefined-undefined-in-chrome-notification-when-its-triggered-from-selenium) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530461/automated-testing-of-chrome-extension-notification)?

Comment: Is the notification coming from a Selenium Driver?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box idea, take a screenshot with Selenium and process the image with OCR? https://github.com/suyesh/ocr_space

I assume Selenium only let’s you interact with the page data.